# I Want to add a Timestamp with the original Name of the Folders name that is being Copied (in vb.net)

Tags: vb.net

I found some Code to Copy a Folder with all its contents to another folder. the Folder name that is being copied to another folder is the same as the original folder in its original path. I want to add a timestamp with a date and time to show you the most recent 'copy' of the folder you copied.

An example would be:
Original Folder: Rage 2 ;
Copied Folder: Rage 2 - 3/11/2021 - 7:37

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    Dim parts As String() = directoryTargetLocation.Split(New Char() {"\"c})
    Dim filename As String = parts(parts.Count - 1) 'target folder name

    Dim dir_path As String = "" 'directory without target folder name
    For f As Integer = 0 To parts.Count - 2
        dir_path += parts(f) + "\"
    Next


    Dim copied As Integer = 0
    Dim counter As Integer = IO.Directory.GetFiles(directoryTargetLocation, "*.*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length 'counts the number of files
    SetProgressbar(counter, ProgressBar2) 'Sets ProgressBar maximum to number of files

    setLabelTxt("Copied (0/" + counter.ToString + ")", Label4) 'displays the amount of copied files

    Dim FolderList As New List(Of String)
    FolderList.Add(directoryTargetLocation) 'Set first folder


    Do While True
        If (BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending = True) Then 'cancel loop
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit Do
        End If

        Dim FoldersInsideDirectory As New List(Of String)

        If FolderList.Count = 0 Then
            Exit Do 'If there is no folder to copy Exit Do
        Else

            For l As Integer = 0 To FolderList.Count - 1

                If (BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending = True) Then 'stop for loop
                    e.Cancel = True
                    Exit For
                End If

                Dim sourceDirectoryInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(FolderList(l))

                Dim dest As String = FolderList(l).Replace(dir_path, "")
                If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(Destinydirectory + "\" + dest)) Then 'create subFolder inside directory
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Destinydirectory + "\" + dest)
                End If

                Dim fileSystemInfo As System.IO.FileSystemInfo

                For Each fileSystemInfo In sourceDirectoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos
                    If (BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending = True) Then
                        e.Cancel = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                    Dim destinationFileName As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(Destinydirectory + "\" + dest, fileSystemInfo.Name)
                    If TypeOf fileSystemInfo Is System.IO.FileInfo Then
                        Dim streamRead As New System.IO.FileStream(fileSystemInfo.FullName, System.IO.FileMode.Open)
                        setLabelTxt(fileSystemInfo.FullName.ToString, LabelProgress)
                        Dim streamWrite As New System.IO.FileStream(Destinydirectory + "\" + dest + "\" + fileSystemInfo.Name, IO.FileMode.Create, IO.FileAccess.Write, IO.FileShare.None)
                        Dim lngLen As Long = streamRead.Length - 1
                        setLabelTxt("Copy bytes : (0/" + (lngLen * 100).ToString + ")", Label10)
                        Dim byteBuffer(1048576) As Byte   'our stream buffer
                        Dim intBytesRead As Integer    'number of bytes read
                        While streamRead.Position < lngLen    'keep streaming until EOF
                            If (BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending = True) Then
                                e.Cancel = True
                                Exit While
                            End If
                            BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(CInt(streamRead.Position / lngLen * 100))
                            setLabelTxt("Copy bytes : (" + CInt(streamRead.Position).ToString + "/" + (lngLen * 100).ToString + ")", Label10)
                            intBytesRead = (streamRead.Read(byteBuffer, 0, 1048576))
                            streamWrite.Write(byteBuffer, 0, intBytesRead)
                        End While
                        'Clean up 
                        streamWrite.Flush()
                        streamWrite.Close()
                        streamRead.Close()
                        addProgress(1, ProgressBar2)
                        copied += 1
                        setLabelTxt("Copied (" + copied.ToString + "/" + counter.ToString + ")", Label4)
                    Else
                        FoldersInsideDirectory.Add(fileSystemInfo.FullName)
                    End If
                Next
            Next
            FolderList.Clear()
            FolderList = FoldersInsideDirectory
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Would you want the timestamp on the highest-level directory only or that and all the subdirectories?

Comment: @AndrewMorton - yes I would only like to add the timestamp to the highest level Directory...not every item within that Directory

Answer (score 0):

Before:

```
Dim streamWrite As New System.IO.FileStream(Destinydirectory + "\" + dest + "\" + fileSystemInfo.Name, IO.FileMode.Create, IO.FileAccess.Write, IO.FileShare.None)
```

After:

```
dim fnbase as string = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileSystemInfo.Name)
dim fnexten as string = path.getextension(fileSystemInfo.Name)
dim fndate as string = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd HHmmss")
dim fn as string = $"{fnbase} - {fndate}{fnexten}"
Dim streamWrite As New System.IO.FileStream(Destinydirectory + "\" + dest + "\" + fn, IO.FileMode.Create, IO.FileAccess.Write, IO.FileShare.None)
```

I broke this down the way I did just so it was really easy for you to see the different pieces of it.  You could just as easily put all of this together dynamically as the value you pass to System.IO.FileStream.

As an aside, you're doing the copy itself the complicated way.  Maybe you need to use that method for a specific reason, but if not, maybe consider `File.Copy` next time.

Comment: Path is not declared - is this the path of the folder I want to copy?

Comment: You just need to add `Imports System.IO`

Comment: This did not work for me as it just copied everything the same way. The name for example Original Folder: Rage 2, Copied Folder is still Rage 2 and its not: Rage 2 - 3/11/2021 - 7:37

Comment: Can you paste the relevant bit of code as an update?

Comment: All I did was add Imports System.IO and Comment out that line you told me from "before" and paste the code from "After"

Comment: Can you either add a break point in your code so you can example the var values, or have it pop a msgbox to display them just before executing the streamwrite?